# Adding a symbol to list elements

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a lists and I have list forms like  :

```
numbers=['1','2','3']
```

I want to transform into :

```
numbers=['-1-','-2-','-3-']
```

I may need to change it later to

```
numbers=['-1-','(2)','-3-']
```

and I will choose which is gonna be . Is there any method or function to do that? .
Sry for my english thanks in advice

Answer (score 2):

The first case is solved by this list comprehension

```
l = [f'-{n}-' for n in numbers]
```

The second one by this for loop, which resembles the previous list comprehension

```
l = []
for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        l.append(f'-{n}-')
    else:
        l.append(f'({n})')
```

Alternatively you can write the `for` loop as a list comprehension as well

```
[f'-{n}' if i % 2 == 0  else f'-({n})-' for i, n in enumerate(numbers)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it's a bit different to the last but ultimately the same:

```
def formatList(listIn,selections):
    l=[]
    for i in range(len(listIn)):
        if not i in selections:
            l.append('-'+str(listIn[i])+'-')
        else:
            l.append('('+str(listIn[i])+')')
    return l
```

where selections as an input would be something like `[2,'''other selections''']` (if you don't know, `'''This is a comment in python (so is this #blahblah but it has to be on the same line)'''`)